# c++20 Sorting Vector of structs with structs member variable and std::ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a simple struct

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
}
```

I have a vector of `MyStruct`s.

```
vector<MyStruct> myStructs;
int n = 10;

for(auto i = 0; i < n; i++)
    myStructs.push_back(MyStruct{.x = n - i});
```

How will I sort `myStructs` according to member variable `.x` using `std::ranges`?

Comment: This page has great example at bottom, how we can use [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using projection:

```
std::ranges::sort(myStructs, {}, &MyStruct::x); //< sort by x
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why i am getting ` error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std::ranges'; did you mean 'std::sort'?`?

Comment: @InyoungKim김인영 It might be the case that your compiler doesn't fully support `ranges` yet.

Comment: @InyoungKim김인영 Or that you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided a member `operator<` (or `operator<=>`) you can do it using a lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::ranges::sort(myStructs, [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { return lhs.x < rhs.x; });
```